# Getting a SyntaxError when running babel from babel-runtime/helpers/typeof-react-element.js (_symbol."for")?

Tags: javascript, npm, syntax-error, babeljs

Project Structure (src contains react component classes using jsx syntax):

```
root
- src/
- package.json
- webpack.config.js
```

Command I'm running: `babel src --out-dir lib`

And here is the error

```
SyntaxError: src/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/typeof-react-element.js: Unexpected token (5:62)
  3 | var _Symbol = require("babel-runtime/core-js/symbol")["default"];
  4 | 
> 5 | exports["default"] = typeof _Symbol === "function" && _Symbol."for" && _Symbol."for"("react.element") || 60103;
    |                                                               ^
  6 | exports.__esModule = true;

npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build:lib"
npm ERR! node v5.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! timber-ui@0.0.1 build:lib: `babel src --out-dir lib`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

here are my top babel devDependencies (not including plugins)

```
"babel-cli": "^6.7.7",
"babel-core": "^6.7.7",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
```

Could this be a legitimate bug in babel? Or perhaps I need a different node version, dependency version? Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try removing them from you package.js file and try install with no version. npm install --save babel-cli babel-core babel-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that a copy of node_modules somehow made it into my src folder. So babel was running against all of node_modules. Also simplified my babel.rc file to just this...

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"]
}
```

After that it works fine. So the issue was either from babel running aginst something weird in node_modules or one of the many plugins I had manually specified before.

The error message is still really confusing but at least I don't think it was any fault of babel.